# one binary sequence to another

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, binary

Consider the binary triple $(0,0,0)$. Now applying a binary addition $(0,0,0)+(1,0,0)=(1,0,0)$. Now apply again to get $(0,0,0)+(1,0,0)+(1,0,0)=(1,0,0)+(1,0,0)=(0,1,0)$.

Repeating this again gives $(0,0,0)+(1,0,0)+(1,0,0)+(1,0,0)=(0,1,0)+(1,0,0)=(1,1,0)$

Repeating this again finally we can land up at the triple (1,1,1). For this case when the size is three I needed 7 steps to arrive at the triple. Is there any general result for no of steps required for $n$-tuple $(0,\cdots,0)$ to arrive at $(1,\cdots,1)$ by adding repeatedly with $(1,0,\cdots,0)$?
I am sorry I couldnt write my doubt properly. I tried to prove it by induction. For the $n=4$, the number I am getting is $15=7+7+1$. I verified one more higher case. for $n=5$, it is $31=15+15+1$ related to the   $n=4$ case.

Comment: *Hint:* $1+2+4+8 = 2^4 - 1 = 15$.

Comment: How do you get $(1,0,0)+(1,0,0)=(0,1,0)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson add the first coordinates. 1+1=0 and 1 is carried to next position and so 1+0=1 and u will get (0,1,0).

Comment: So you are writing $(1,0,0)$ for what's usually written as $001_2$? You're just writing the numbers $1,2,3,\dots$ in binary: $0,1,10,11,100,101,110,111,\dots$. Then for example $111$ in binary is $7$, which is why it takes you seven steps to get there; $1111$ is $15$ in binary, $11111$ is $31$, and so on. It's a little easier to get the formula if you go one step further, to $1000_2=8_{10}$, $10000_2=16_{10}$, $100000_2=32_{10}$, and so on.

Comment: Understood, budi?

Comment: Are you still here, budi?

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.

Comment: Good. You could write up your understanding, and post it as an answer.